# WooCommerce - Editar click sobre produto

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Olá, gostaria de saber onde posso editar o evento click na imagem do produto quando ele for de um site externo (afiliado). 
Por exemplo, tenho uma loja com alguns produtos próprios e outros que sou afiliado, gostaria que quando clicasse em algum de afiliado o cliente fosse direcionado direto para a página.

Atualmente o cliente é direcionado para uma página dentro do meu site (descrição do produto) e se ele clicar em comprar é que será enviado para o site externo.

Consegui fazer isso, porém só gostaria que fosse em nova aba, alguma dica?

Ficou confuso ou deu para entender?